# Gmail not being retrieved automatically

Tags: gmail, motorola-droid-x, sync

I have recently (since ~1month ago) experienced the following **problem**:

- When I get new mail on my gmail account, Gmail will **usually** not autimatically retrieve it (e.g., no notification; and when I manually open GMail app, the mail will NOT be in the inbox)
- However, **manual** mail retrieval/sync **DOES** work fine, for example if I click on "Sync" (retreieve) curcle icon within GMail app; or on Elixir 2's "start background data sync" icon; or check-off-and-back-on on the "Mail Sync" in Settings->Accounts for relevant Google account.
- Also, **sometimes** Gmail does get retrieved/notified; I am not 100% sure but there seems to be a very strong correllation between that and having recently opened GMail app (especially in foreground).
- GMail sync worked perfectly find till ~1 month ago
- The background sync does not work for ANY of the 3 Gmail accounts I registered.
- **OTHER mail apps seem to sync perfectly fine (e.g. Hotmail or Yahoo mail) in the background.**. So I have a hard time believing it is a problem with overall sync.
- The issue is independent of network - it doesn't work on WiFi or 3G.

**System details:**

- Droid X, running rooted stock Froyo 2.2.
- I have gone through 100% of intents in [Autostarts](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=autostart&fdid=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts) and made sure every single intent is ON for both Gmail listener and Google Framework.
- Gmail version is 2.3.6 (it has a 7/1/2012 backup in Titanium Backup Pro, so I'm assuming this is when it was last updated. BUT the problem existed before 7/1)
- **Background sync is turned ON - confirmed via Quick Settings app as well as widgets from Elixir 2.**  (also, as noted above, Hotmail and Yahoo mail seem to sync fine)

Comment: Have you considered the network condition? Did you "Enable always-on mobile data" in Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks?

Comment: Yes, and yes. If you carefully read the question: (1) OTHER mail apps sync in background; (2) Gmail almost NEVER syncs automatically (unless the app is running in foreground and was just synced manually before).

Comment: Try looking into logcat for any errors relating to GMail.

Comment: Is Gmail sync on? And lose that task manager.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik - How can I tell if Gmail sync is on or off? Settings->Accounts has "Mail" turned on. And ATK is kind of irrelevant here - Gmail is whitelisted, so are pretty much all server processes except the ones I 100% know are safe to kill. And it was this way for >1 year.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  After reading kevinf's answer, I found the solution by checking the general Google sync settings.  Gmail was not checked!

```
Settings->Accounts/Google->YourEmail@gmail.com Last synced MM/DD/YYYY 12:00 PM->List of Google Sync Settings.
```

As a side note, the Gmail app indicated that sync was turned off.

```
Gmail App->Menu/Settings->YourEmail@gmail.com->DATA USAGE/Gmail sync is OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, Gmail sync would rarely work, for 3G and for Wifi.

My Galaxy S3 runs 4.0.4 stock ICS, background sync is enabled, and so is a mobile data limit. Wifi is set to sleep on display off.

What I didn't realize, is in the Settings -> Data usage -> Gmail, I accidentally checked the box "restrict background data". This correlates to "Also, sometimes Gmail does get retrieved/notified; I am not 100% sure but there seems to be a very strong correllation between that and having recently opened GMail app (especially in foreground)."

Wifi background sync *should* work, but if you have Wifi to sleep when screen off, then you still would fail to get notifications!

Comment: This doesn't apply since my problem was on 3G, not wifi. Interestingly, **my GMail problem went away on its own**, but instead now my Hotmail notifications have exactly the same problem.

Comment: This does apply, as I had the problem with both Wifi AND 3G.
Glad to hear your problem went away, but there is no such thing as random events, everything has a cause.
 
Do you have an application "Light Manager", it can mess with notifications...

Comment: OK, I figured out Hotmail problem. For some strange reason, some of the Hotmail intents were **turned off**. I turned them back on in Autostarts. I STILL have no clue about Gmail